# Evaluating $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{\pi-x}} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

$$
\int_0^\pi \sqrt{\frac{\sin x}{\pi-x}} \, dx
$$
I have stumbled upon this integral and have no clue how to solve it. 
I know the answer is around $2.2778$. I tried some expansions and some approximations without success. Can you guys figure it out?

Comment: Well, there are no functions to describe the antiderivative.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt%28sin%28x%29%2F%28pi-x%29%29dx+from+0+to+pi&x=8&y=7) can't find a closed form, which lowers the probability that there is one.

Comment: A simple substitution shows that this is the same as $$ \int_0^\pi \sqrt{\frac{\sin x} x} \, dx, $$ but as far as I know that doesn't get you closer to evaluating it.

Comment: @MarkViola Probably you want to write$$2\int_0^{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\sqrt{\sin(x^2)}}{x}\,dx$$ instead of $$2\int_0^{\sqrt{\pi}}\sqrt{\sin(x^2)}\,dx$$ in the last step.

Comment: @jaideepkhare No, there is no $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: The Taylor series of $\sqrt{\sin x/x}$ is described by a couple of OEIS entries, which suggests that other people have found it interesting: http://oeis.org/A008991 http://oeis.org/A008992 . There may be a connection to the Catalan numbers: http://oeis.org/A220002 . If the exponent had been an integer rather than 1/2, you could have applied eq. 37 from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html .

Comment: @MarkViola Oh!! Sorry,  I forgot replace $\mathrm dx$ with $\mathrm dt$ after substituting $x=t^2$.

Answer (score 2):

> *Can you guys figure it out ?*

No. We cannot. And for a very good reason. Basically, you have asked us to evaluate $I\bigg(\dfrac12\bigg),$

where $I(a)~=~\displaystyle\int_0^\pi\bigg(\frac{\sin x}x\bigg)^a~dx~=~\frac12~\int_{-\pi}^\pi\bigg(\frac{\sin x}x\bigg)^a~dx.~$ However, even the simpler and

much more [notorious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) $I(1)~=~\text{Si}(\pi)~$ is [not](http://oeis.org/A036792) [known](http://oeis.org/A036793) to possess a [meaningful](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wilbraham-GibbsConstant.html) closed form, so it

would be rather surprising if *this* one did.